# Disable padding between functions in Visual Studio 2022

Tags: c#, visual-studio

Visual Studio 2022 IDE adds a weird padding between the functions written. It is like a new space but there is no new space. Just padding. I want to disable this padding. Is it possible?

[image]

Comment: In what language?

Comment: Does it matter? I am writing in C#.

Comment: It might, there's separate language settings in the "Text Editor" section of your options. Screenshot would be helpful in determining what you're talking about. Also, if you run things like resharper or codemaid that may be changing some things too.

Comment: @LarryBud Added a screenshot

Comment: assuming you can't put a cursor there, that's where CodeLens puts it's info. Try disabling it in your options.

Answer (score 0):

Try disabling codelens, this "new line" is where the reference count goes
Tools --> Options --> Text Editor --> All Languages --> Codelens --> Uncheck Enable Codelens

Comment: what's interesting is that there's no info on that line for him at all.